# Strong determinacy principles

Tags: set-theory, determinacy

It seems to be a well-known result that $\mathrm{AD}_{\omega_1}$ and $\mathrm{AD}_{\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R})}$ (determinacy of $\omega$-length games with moves in $\omega_1$ or $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R})$, respectively) are inconsistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ even in the absence of choice. (See [Limitations of determinacy hypotheses in ZFC](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271507/limitations-of-determinacy-hypotheses-in-zfc).)

(1) Does anyone know of a published source for the proof?

(2) Is it known whether these principles are inconsistent with Zermelo set theory alone in the absence of replacement?

Comment: I"m pretty sure the $\omega_1$-case was already in Mycielski's original paper on AD. The case of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ follows, since $\omega_1$ embeds in $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, but it's also easy to prove directly: Determinacy for games over $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ implies the existence of a choice function on $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)-\{\varnothing\}$, which implies that $\mathbb R$ can be well-oredered, contrary to AD.